# Constructing select box according to the input in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here in the code While clicking the first select it will send the request to route.php and get the result and it will display the output int he `<div id="result">`

But what i need is the both select box should be there in the first page itself and while selecting it should send result to the route.php and the value should be filled in the second select box (Until first select box is selected the second select should say please select above )

Here is my Code for Jquery post and request

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="name">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
<div id='result' name="result">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").change(function(){
    var name=$("#name").val();
    $.post("route.php",
    {
      name:name
    },
    function(data,status){
       $( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

And the route.php is

```
<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
<select  id="name">
  <option value="volvo" selected><?php echo $a;?></option>
  <option value="audi" >b</option>
  <option value="audi" >v</option>
</select>
```

How can i do this ?

### Update :

**Suppose i follow the below code And i want to do it for n number of times. Is that possible ?**

**HTML :**

```
<div id='result' name="result">
<select  id="result-name">
  <option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").change(function(){
    var name=$("#name").val();
    $.post("route.php",
    {
      name:name
    },
    function(data,status){
       $( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

**route.php**

```
<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
<select  id="result-name">
  <option value="volvo" selected><?php echo $a;?></option>
  <option value="audi" >b</option>
  <option value="audi" >v</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why can't you construct the second `select` under this part -> `function(data,status){}`

Comment: But it won't visible before the first request was sent right ?

Comment: Why don't you put your second select disabled initially and later while replacing it gets enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is good idea, at the same time the select should have option element which is returned by the route.php file, How it can be done, and that is what i am looking far

Comment: @BizDev Construct the `select` outside the AJAX call. That way your `select` will always be visible. Then add the `option` values inside the AJAX return function.

Comment: @Hashbrown : Is it possible to fill the select list with the values that is returned by the route.php ?

Comment: @BizDev see my answer below

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check my updated quesetion.\

Comment: Your question was how to make the second `select` dropdown to show up immediately. That part has been answered by many. You changed it to how to append to the second `select` dropdown when multiple boxes are selected in the first `select`. That is another question. Don't keep changing the question, submit a new one with adjusted code.

Comment: yes, i shall ask it in a separate question. Anyway, Thanks for the answer

Comment: The answers given will be easier to find for people who are searching for similar issues. Thanks, and good luck of course :)

Comment: Thanks i understand, thus contributing to SO !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="name">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
<div id='result' name="result">
<select  id="result-name">
  <option value="" disabled>Please select above</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").change(function(){
    var name=$("#name").val();
    $.post("route.php",
    {
      name:name
    },
    function(data,status){
       $( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

the other file can stay the same:

```
<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
<select  id="result-name">
  <option value="volvo" selected><?php echo $a;?></option>
  <option value="audi" >b</option>
  <option value="audi" >v</option>
</select>
```

use either append or replace to get the code in the right spot.
You can choose to just return the `options`, or the complete `selection` part

Comment: I followed your code, And saw the page source, i didn't able to see the value of replaced code.. Consider if i am doing another same request like this , Will that be possible ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: You could use `replaceWith()` to update the result multiple times

Comment: In which place should i use the replaceWith() ?

Comment: No, i mean the option select should be generated below one by one while the top list is selected

Comment: then `append()` is a better option. You will probably need a different script because no doubt your next question will be how to remove an option when someone deselects an option in the first `select`, right?

Comment: okies, i shall ask it in seperate question . +1 for your answer , upvote if my first question looks ok

Answer (score 1):

You can try simple with select element itself,

```
<select id='result' name="result">
     <option>---Please select above value first---</option>
</select>
```

and route.php

```
<?php
$a = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
  <option value="volvo" selected><?php echo $a;?></option>
  <option value="audi" >b</option>
  <option value="audi" >v</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct the select outside the AJAX call. That way your select will always be visible.

```
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Then add the option values inside the AJAX return function.

```
function(data,status){
  $("#sel").append( '<option value="volvo" selected>' + data + '</option>' ); 
  $("#sel").append( '<option value="audi" >b</option>' );
  ...
}
```

**Based on the Updated Question**

You want whenever you change the value of a `select` in that `DIV`, it should bring in a new `SELECT` and this should continue to happen for `n` times. I attempted the same below but could not test it right-away. The idea is, you use `on` event delegation to keep track of any change in Select, if detected, you call the Ajax and append the result.

HTML

```
<div id="result">
<select><option>Please select</option></select>
</div>
```

jQUERY

```
<script>
  $("#result select").on ('change', function(){
    var name=$("#name").val();
    $.post("route.php",
    {
      name:name
    },
    function(data,status){
       $( "#result" ).append ( data );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my question. Can you say whether is that possible ?

Comment: @BizDev I looked into your updated code. It seems to be correct already. What issue are you facing there? Do you want the previous `options` to retain their values when you again change the `#name`?

Comment: No, if the first option select is selected it is constructing another select box under it right, Similar way while i select the second select, it should construct another select box under it and it should continue n times after that